# GPU run out of memory while fine tuning Llama 2 with 2 RTX 4090

Tags: pytorch, large-language-model, llama

I am currently working on fine-tuning the Llama-2-7b-chat-hf model using a custom dataset and utilizing two RTX 4090 GPUs for this process. Despite experimenting with various approaches, I consistently encounter a "CUDA out of memory" error. Given the hardware at my disposal, I am trying to determine whether the issue lies with the GPU resources or if there might be inefficiencies or errors within my code that are leading to this problem. Below, I've provided the code I'm using for reference, in hopes of identifying the root cause of the memory issue.

```
# %%
import os
import torch
from datasets import load_dataset
from transformers import (
    AutoModelForCausalLM,
    AutoTokenizer,
    BitsAndBytesConfig,
    HfArgumentParser,
    TrainingArguments,
    pipeline,
    logging,
    TextDataset,
    DataCollatorForLanguageModeling,
    Trainer

)
from datasets import Dataset
from peft import LoraConfig, PeftModel
from trl import SFTTrainer
import pandas as pd
import json
import gc

# %%
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0,1"
gc.collect()
os.environ["PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF"] = "max_split_size_mb:40000"

# %%
base_model = r"***"
new_model = r"***"

# %%
json_dataset =  load_dataset("json", data_files="***")
json_dataset = pd.DataFrame(json_dataset['train'])
#print(json_dataset)

# %%
device = torch.device("cuda") if torch.cuda.is_available() else torch.device("cpu")

# %%
bnb_config = BitsAndBytesConfig(
    load_in_4bit=True,
    bnb_4bit_use_double_quant=True,
    bnb_4bit_quant_type="nf4",
    bnb_4bit_compute_dtype=torch.bfloat16
)

# %%
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(base_model)

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(base_model, trust_remote_code=True)
tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token
tokenizer.padding_side = "right"
model.config.pretraining_tp = 1

tokenized_dataset = updated_dataset.map(
    tokenize_function,
    batched=True,
    batch_size=1,
    drop_last_batch=True
)

print(tokenized_dataset)

# %%
tokenized_dataset = tokenized_dataset.add_column("labels", tokenized_dataset["input_ids"])
print(tokenized_dataset)

# %%
for i in range(5):
    print(tokenized_dataset[i])


# %%
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir = "***",
    overwrite_output_dir=True,
    num_train_epochs=2,
    gradient_accumulation_steps=1,
    fp16=True,
    bf16=False,
    per_device_train_batch_size=1,
    optim="paged_adamw_8bit",
    save_steps=200,
    logging_steps=25,
    save_total_limit=2,
    max_grad_norm=0.3,
    max_steps=-1,
    group_by_length=True,
    learning_rate=2e-3,
    weight_decay=0.01,
    warmup_steps=10,
    lr_scheduler_type="linear",
)

# %%
peft_params = LoraConfig(lora_alpha=16, 
                         lora_dropout=0.1, 
                         r=64, 
                         bias="none", 
                         task_type="CAUSAL_LM")

# %%
gc.collect()
torch.cuda.empty_cache()

#4-Bit Quantization( use this if you want to quantize the model using PEFT) 
os.environ["PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF"] = "max_split_size_mb:40000"
trainer = SFTTrainer(model=model, 
                     train_dataset=tokenized_dataset, 
                     peft_config=peft_params, 
                     tokenizer=tokenizer, 
                     args=training_args, 
                     dataset_text_field="text")

# %%
trainer.train()
trainer.model.save_pretrained(new_model)
trainer.tokenizer.save_pretrained(new_model)
gc.collect()
torch.cuda.empty_cache()
```

I think maybe data parallelism is solution or model pruning. however i dont have knowledge about it.